# Is brewing plum alcohol forming mold like this suitable to make fertiliser or discarding?

Tags: fertilizer, mold

I have a jar of plum alcohol that it is forming mold already due to the uncovered area not being filled with alcohol again. So would like to know what is the best use of it such as the possibility of making fertiliser for planting or can only discard it?

[image]

Comment: Because it has been exposed to organisms like mold , you will likely find the alcohol has also been converted to vinegar.

Comment: You could compost it.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Thanks, I am too bad in chemistry in middle school LOL, so if it is vinegar, does it good or bad to soil as fertiliser?

Comment: @aparente001 What is the righteous method or procedure to compost it? If it involves a certain operation, you may answer the question so that it could benefit to other searchers. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: There are lots of ways to compost, I'll let you enjoy reading about it.

Comment: @西門正CodeGuy Vinegar shouldn't hurt your soil; it might reduce pH a little. However, if you put it on a plant in high concentration when the sun is out, it might kill the plant. Vinegar has been used in low concentrations as a foliar spray on plants for a number of benefits (but most people recognize it as a herbicide, which takes more of it). The benefit of vinegar isn't the NPK, though, I'm thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yes, (it is eligible to) put it into the compost bin. Because Mold is actually an agent of composting. Moldy food is food that has partly composted.

This answer is found [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-okay-to-put-moldy-food-in-the-compost-green-bin/answer/John-Jayne-3?ch=10&oid=177448118&share=54d09b0d&srid=p1n4E&target_type=answer) by and credit to John Jayne.

Simple yet precise so I quote his words with a little bit of words adding.